# Problema Ruta laravel para genear pdf

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema con una ruta en especifico en laravel, no se realmente que está mal, pues la idea de esa ruta es que me genere un pdf, a partir del tipo y rango de fechas seleccionadas en una vista, pero me da error 404 en consola como no encontrado en el último parámetro. Gracias

Mi ruta:

```
 Route::get('/report/pdf/{$rptId}/{$fechaTo}/{$fechaFrom}',[ReportController::class,'ReportPDF']);
```

Mi anchor

```
             <a href="{{url('report/pdf/'  . $report . '/' . $fechaTo . '/' . $fechaFrom) }}" class="btn btn-danger {{$fechaFrom?? 'disabled'}}" target="_blank">Confirmar</a>
```

Mi controlador

```
   public function ReportPDF1($reportId,$fechaTo=null,$fechaFrom=null){
        switch($reportId) {
            case('1'):
                $fecha= (new DateTime($fechaTo))->format('Y-m-d');
               //Saco producccion 
                $prod_anterior= Oil::select('oil','agua','total')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->first();  
                $prod_anterior = $prod_anterior ??  0;                
                $prod_fecha= Oil::select('oil','agua','total')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->first();   
                $prod_fecha = $prod_fecha ??  0;              
                $prod_gas= Gasse::select('a9300')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->first();  
                $prod_gas = $prod_gas ??  0;
                $ventas= Sale::select('total')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->first();
                $ventas = $ventas ??  0;                           
                
                $datosprod=array(
                    'oil'=>round(($oil = $prod_fecha->oil ??  0)-($oil = $prod_anterior->oil ??  0),2),
                    'agua'=>round(($agua = $prod_fecha->agua ??  0)-($agua = $prod_anterior->agua ??  0),2),
                    'total'=>round(($total = $prod_fecha->total ??  0)-($total = $prod_anterior->total ??  0),2),
                    'gas' =>$gas = $prod_gas->a9300 ??  0,
                    'ventas'=>$ventas = $ventas->total ??  0,
                );   
                $title="Reporte Producción";
                $dataWellVariation = WellVariation::select('*')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->get(); 
                $dataWellDownTime = WellDownTime::select('*')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->get(); 
                $dataWellControl = WellControl::select('*')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->get(); 
                $dataWellIntervention = WellIntervention::select('*')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->get();
                $dataCompressorDownTime = CompressorDownTime::select('*')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->get();               
                $dataNovedades = Post::select('*')->where([ 'fecha' =>$fecha])->get(); 
                $pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
                $pdf->loadView('pages.report.html.parte', compact('datosprod','dataWellVariation',
                'dataWellDownTime','dataWellControl','dataWellIntervention',
                'dataCompressorDownTime','dataNovedades','title'));
                return $pdf->stream('Parte_Produccion.pdf');
               
                
                break;

            case('2'):
                break;

        }
```

Comment: Los parámetros de las rutas no llevan el signo $, solo caracteres alfanuméricos y guión bajo

Comment: gracias, era eso,

Comment: ¿Te parece si la cerramos entonces? Porque ya que está especificado en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters) > *Route parameters are always encased within {} braces and should consist of alphabetic characters. Underscores (_) are also acceptable within route parameter names*, ponerle un caracter no válido sería un error de sintaxis